# Getting this error message "ERROR 1064 (42000)" when creating Table

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

```
create table `Salary`(
`sa_id` int unsigned,
`es_id` int unsigned,
`po_id` int unsigned,
`value` int (10),
`lose` int (10),
`days` int (10),
`lose_note` varchar (50),
PRIMARY KEY(`sa_id`),
CONSTRAINT po_sa FOREIGN KEY (`po_id`)
REFERENCES Position(`po_id`)
CONSTRAINT es_sa FOREIGN KEY (`es_id`)
REFERENCES Employee_stat(`es_id`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT="Table";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it appears position without backticks and a missing comma are the problem.

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a47d3)

```
create table `Salary`(
`sa_id` int unsigned,
`es_id` int unsigned,
`po_id` int unsigned,
`value` int (10),
`lose` int (10),
`days` int (10),
`lose_note` varchar (50),
PRIMARY KEY(`sa_id`),
CONSTRAINT po_sa FOREIGN KEY (`po_id`)
REFERENCES `Position`(`po_id`),  --Backticks & comma
CONSTRAINT es_sa FOREIGN KEY (`es_id`)
REFERENCES Employee_stat(`es_id`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT="Table";
```

Comment: I've no idea why position requires backticks though... it's not on the reserved word list when I checked...

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a comma after `REFERENCES Position(po_id)`

Answer (score 1):

Comma missed after the first REFERENCES. Your query will be:

```
CREATE TABLE `Salary`(
    `sa_id` int unsigned,
    `es_id` int unsigned,
    `po_id` int unsigned,
    `value` int (10),
    `lose` int (10),
    `days` int (10),
    `lose_note` varchar (50),
    PRIMARY KEY(`sa_id`),
    CONSTRAINT po_sa FOREIGN KEY (`po_id`)
    REFERENCES Position(`po_id`), -- missed the comma here
    CONSTRAINT es_sa FOREIGN KEY (`es_id`)
    REFERENCES Employee_stat(`es_id`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT="Table";
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a missing `,` operator as shown below

```
PRIMARY KEY(`sa_id`),
CONSTRAINT po_sa FOREIGN KEY (`po_id`) <-- Here
```

Change your `CREATE TABLE` statement to be

```
create table `Salary`(
`sa_id` int unsigned,
`es_id` int unsigned,
`po_id` int unsigned,
`value` int (10),
`lose` int (10),
`days` int (10),
`lose_note` varchar (50),
PRIMARY KEY(`sa_id`),
CONSTRAINT po_sa FOREIGN KEY (`po_id`),
REFERENCES Position(`po_id`),
CONSTRAINT es_sa FOREIGN KEY (`es_id`),
REFERENCES Employee_stat(`es_id`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT="Table";
```